# mypy - callable with derived classes gives error

Tags: python, mypy

```
class BaseClass:
    p: int

class DerivedClass(BaseClass):
    q: int

def p(q: Callable[[BaseClass], str]) -> None:
    return None

def r(derived: DerivedClass) -> str:
    return ""

p(r)
```

Expected behavior:

- No error from `mypy` -

Actual behavior:

```
Argument 1 to "p" has incompatible type "Callable[[DerivedClass], str]"; 
    expected "Callable[[BaseClass], str]"
```

Answer (score 13):

Let's talk about [type variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)). Under typical subtyping rules, if we have a type `DerivedClass` that is a subtype of a type `BaseClass`, then every instance of `DerivedClass` is an instance of `BaseClass`. Simple enough, right? But now the complexity arises when we have generic type arguments.

Let's suppose that we have a class that gets a value and returns it. I don't know how it gets it; maybe it queries a database, maybe it reads the file system, maybe it just makes one up. But it gets a value.

```
class Getter:
    def get_value(self):
        # Some deep magic ...
```

Now let's assume that, when we construct the `Getter`, we know what type it should be querying at compile-time. We can use a type variable to annotate this.

```
T = TypeVar("T")
class Getter(Generic[T]):
    def get_value(self) -> T:
        ...
```

Now, `Getter` is a valid thing. We can have a `Getter[int]` which gets an integer and a `Getter[str]` which gets a string.

But here's a question. If I have a `Getter[int]`, is that a valid `Getter[object]`? Surely, if I can get a value as an `int`, it's easy enough to upcast it, right?

```
my_getter_int: Getter[int] = ...
my_getter_obj: Getter[object] = my_getter_int
```

But Python won't allow this. See, `Getter` was declared to be *invariant* in its type argument. That's a fancy way of saying that, even though `int` is a subtype of `object`, `Getter[int]` and `Getter[object]` have *no* relationship.

But, like I said, surely they *should* have a relationship, right? Well, yes. If your type is only used in *positive* position (glossing over some details, that means roughly that it only appears as the return value of methods or as the type of read-only properties), then we can make it covariant.

```
T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)
class Getter(Generic[T_co]):
    def get_value(self) -> T_co:
        ...
```

By convention, in Python, we denote covariant type arguments using names that end in `_co`. But the thing that actually makes it covariant here is the `covariant=True` keyword argument.

Now, with *this* version of `Getter`, `Getter[int]` is actually a subtype of `Getter[object]`. In general, if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `Getter[A]` is a subtype of `Getter[B]`. Covariance preserves subtyping.

Okay, that's covariance. Now consider the opposite. Let's say we have a *setter* which sets some value in a database.

```
class Setter:
    def set_value(self, value):
        ...
```

Same assumptions as before. Suppose we know what the type is in advance. Nowe we write

```
T = TypeVar("T")
class Setter:
    def set_value(self, value: T) -> None:
        ...
```

Okay, great. Now, if I have a value `my_setter : Setter[int]`, is that a `Setter[object]`? Well, `my_setter` can always take an integer value, whereas a `Setter[object]` is *guaranteed* to be able to take *any* object. `my_setter` can't guarantee that, so it's actually not. If we try to make `T` covariant in this example, we'll get

```
error: Cannot use a covariant type variable as a parameter
```

Because it's actually not a valid relationship. In fact, in this case, we get the opposite relationship. If we have a `my_setter : Setter[object]`, then that's a guarantee that we can pass it *any* object at all, so certainly we can pass it an integer, hence we have a `Setter[int]`. This is called *contravariance*.

```
T_contra = TypeVar("T_contra", contravariant=True)
class Setter:
    def set_value(self, value: T_contra) -> None:
        ...
```

We can make our type contravariant if it only appears in *negative* position, which (again, oversimplifying a bit) generally means that it appears as arguments to functions, but not as a return value. Now, `Setter[object]` is a subtype of `Setter[int]`. It's backwards. In general, if `A` is a subtype of `B`, then `Setter[B]` is a subtype of `Setter[A]`. Contravariance *reverses* the subtyping relationship.

Now, back to your example. You have a `Callable[[DerivedClass], str]` and want to know if it's a valid `Callable[[BaseClass], str]`

Applying our principles from before, we have a type `Callable[[T], S]` (I'm assuming only one argument for simplicity's sake, but in reality this works in Python for any number of arguments) and want to ask if `T` and `S` are covariant, contravariant, or invariant.

Well, what is a `Callable`? It's a function. It has one thing we can do: call it with a `T` and get an `S`. So it's pretty clear that `T` is only used as an argument and `S` as a result. Things only used as arguments are contravariant, and those used as results are covariant, so in reality it's more correct to write

```
Callable[[T_contra], S_co]
```

Arguments to `Callable` are contravariant, which means that if `DerivedClass` is a subtype of `BaseClass`, then `Callable[[BaseClass], str]` is a subtype of `Callable[[DerivedClass], str]`, the opposite relationship to the one you suggested. You need a function that can accept *any* `BaseClass`. A function with a `BaseClass` argument would suffice, and so would a function with an `object` argument, or any type which is a supertype of `BaseClass`, but subtypes are insufficient because they're too specific for your contract.

Answer (score 0):

MyPy objects to your call of `p` with `r` as its argument because given only the type signatures, it can't be sure the function won't be called with a non-`DerivedClass` instance.

For instance, given the same type annotations, `p` could be implemented like this:

```
def p(q: Callable[[BaseClass], str]) -> None:
    obj = BaseClass()
    q(obj)
```

This will break `p(r)` if `r` has an implementation that depends on the derived attributes of its argument:

```
def r(derived: DerivedClass) -> str:
    return str(derived.q)
```