# Class method override with any type of property

Tags: python, python-typing

I am trying to create a method override, and I am not sure how to make it so that the override doesn't throw the following error:

```
Method "main" overrides class "App" in an incompatible manner
  Parameter 2 type mismatch: base parameter is type "object", override parameter is type "Tuple[str, int, int]"
    "object" is incompatible with "Tuple[str, int, int]"
```

I Understand that the two types are different, but since object is a base class shouldn't this be allowed? I have strict turned on, so an error is thrown when I use `any` which is what I would like to keep turned on.

```py
class App:
    @abstractmethod
    def main(self, params: object):
        pass

class MyClass(App):
    def main(self, params: Tuple[str, int, int]):
        # Do something
```

What is the proper way to override a method and allow a parameter to be of any type (while using strict typing)?

Comment: I am not sure if this changes your comment or not, but I made `main` abstract. How do I set the type without knowing what values will be passed to `params`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the variance backwards.

```
class App:
  @abstractmethod
  def main(self, params: object):
    pass
```

This is a *promise*. It says "any class which implements `App` has a `main` which works on *all* objects. Not some of them. *All* of them.

Then you come along and write

```
class MyClass(App):
  def main(self, params: Tuple[str, int, int]):
    # Do something
```

So `MyClass` has a `main` which works on a specific type of parameter, not all of them. Your type checker correctly reports that this is not what you promised earlier. You could do the opposite thing: If `App` requires `Tuple[str, int, int]`, then `MyClass` could implement a version for `object`, since that includes `Tuple[str, int, int]` and then some.

But for your case, you probably want generics.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

_T_contra = TypeVar("_T_contra", contravariant=True)

class App(Generic[_T_contra]):
  @abstractmethod
  def main(self, params: _T_contra) -> None:
    pass

class MyClass(App[Tuple[str, int, int]]):
  def main(self, params: Tuple[str, int, int]):
    # Do something
```

Now `MyClass` doesn't claim to work for all objects. It claims to work for this specific type, so it derives from a *specific* `App`.

For a discussion of why it's `_T_contra` (a *contravariant* type parameter), you can read [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185931/mypy-callable-with-derived-classes-gives-error/68186433#68186433) where I go into more detail on variance annotations in Python.